# How to get accurate timing using microphone in python

Tags: python, signal-processing, detection, timing, pyaudio

I'm trying to make beat detection using PC microphone and then with timestamp of beat calculate distance between multiple successive beats. I have chosen python because there is plenty of material available and it's quick to develop. By searching the internet I have come up with this simple code (no advanced peak detection or anything yet, this comes later if need be):

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import math
import time


SHORT_NORMALIZE = (1.0/32768.0)


def get_rms(block):
    # RMS amplitude is defined as the square root of the
    # mean over time of the square of the amplitude.
    # so we need to convert this string of bytes into
    # a string of 16-bit samples...

    # we will get one short out for each
    # two chars in the string.
    count = len(block)/2
    format = "%dh" % (count)
    shorts = struct.unpack(format, block)

    # iterate over the block.
    sum_squares = 0.0
    for sample in shorts:
        # sample is a signed short in +/- 32768.
        # normalize it to 1.0
        n = sample * SHORT_NORMALIZE
        sum_squares += n*n

    return math.sqrt(sum_squares / count)


CHUNK = 32
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

elapsed_time = 0
prev_detect_time = 0

while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    amplitude = get_rms(data)
    if amplitude > 0.05:  # value set by observing graphed data captured from mic
        elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - prev_detect_time
        if elapsed_time > 0.1:  # guard against multiple spikes at beat point
            print(elapsed_time)
            prev_detect_time = time.perf_counter()

def close_stream():
  stream.stop_stream()
  stream.close()
  p.terminate()
```

The code works pretty good in silence, and I have been pretty satisfied the first two moments I ran it, but then I tried how accurate it was and I was a little bit less satisfied. To test this I used two methods: phone with metronome set to 60bpm (emits tic toc sounds into microphone) and an Arduino hooked to a beeper, which is triggered at 1Hz rate by accurate Chronodot RTC. The beeper beeps into microphone, triggering a detection. With both methods results look similar (numbers represent distance between two beat detections in seconds):

```
0.9956681643835616
1.0056331689497717
0.9956100091324198
1.0058207853881278
0.9953449497716891
1.0052103013698623
1.0049350136986295
0.9859074337899543
1.004996383561644
0.9954095342465745
1.0061518904109583
0.9953025753424658
1.0051235068493156
1.0057199634703196
0.984839305936072
1.00610396347032
0.9951862648401821
1.0053146301369864
0.9960100821917806
1.0053391780821919
0.9947373881278523
1.0058608219178105
1.0056580091324214
0.9852110319634697
1.0054473059360731
0.9950465753424638
1.0058237077625556
0.995704694063928
1.0054566575342463
0.9851026118721435
1.0059882374429243
1.0052523835616398
0.9956161461187207
1.0050863926940607
0.9955758173515932
1.0058052968036577
0.9953960913242028
1.0048014611872205
1.006336876712325
0.9847434520547935
1.0059712876712297
```

Now I'm pretty confident that at least Arduino is accurate to 1 msec (which is targeted accuracy). The results tend to be off by +- 5msec, but now and then even 15ms, which is unacceptable. Is there a way to achieve greater accuracy or is this limitation of python / soundcard / something else? Thank you!

EDIT:
After incorporating tom10 and barny's suggestions into the code, the code looks like this:

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import math
import psutil
import os


def set_high_priority():
    p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    p.nice(psutil.HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS)


SHORT_NORMALIZE = (1.0/32768.0)


def get_rms(block):
    # RMS amplitude is defined as the square root of the
    # mean over time of the square of the amplitude.
    # so we need to convert this string of bytes into
    # a string of 16-bit samples...

    # we will get one short out for each
    # two chars in the string.
    count = len(block)/2
    format = "%dh" % (count)
    shorts = struct.unpack(format, block)

    # iterate over the block.
    sum_squares = 0.0
    for sample in shorts:
        # sample is a signed short in +/- 32768.
        # normalize it to 1.0
        n = sample * SHORT_NORMALIZE
        sum_squares += n*n

    return math.sqrt(sum_squares / count)


CHUNK = 4096
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RUNTIME_SECONDS = 10

set_high_priority()

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

elapsed_time = 0
prev_detect_time = 0
TIME_PER_CHUNK = 1000 / RATE * CHUNK
SAMPLE_GROUP_SIZE = 32  # 1 sample = 2 bytes, group is closest to 1 msec elapsing
TIME_PER_GROUP = 1000 / RATE * SAMPLE_GROUP_SIZE

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RUNTIME_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    time_in_chunk = 0
    group_index = 0
    for j in range(0, len(data), (SAMPLE_GROUP_SIZE * 2)):
        group = data[j:(j + (SAMPLE_GROUP_SIZE * 2))]
        amplitude = get_rms(group)
        amplitudes.append(amplitude)
        if amplitude > 0.02:
            current_time = (elapsed_time + time_in_chunk)
            time_since_last_beat = current_time - prev_detect_time
            if time_since_last_beat > 500:
                print(time_since_last_beat)
                prev_detect_time = current_time
        time_in_chunk = (group_index+1) * TIME_PER_GROUP
        group_index += 1
    elapsed_time = (i+1) * TIME_PER_CHUNK

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

With this code I achieved the following results (units are this time milliseconds instead of seconds):

```
999.909297052154
999.9092970521542
999.9092970521542
999.9092970521542
999.9092970521542
1000.6349206349205
999.9092970521551
999.9092970521524
999.9092970521542
999.909297052156
999.9092970521542
999.9092970521542
999.9092970521524
999.9092970521542
```

Which, if I didn't make any mistake, looks a lot better than before and has achieved sub-millisecond accuracy. I thank tom10 and barny for their help.

Comment: Whether on Windows or Linux PC/Raspberry Pi, expecting sub-millisecond timing accuracy from user-space applications (i.e. not just Python) you are going to be disappointed because your PC has many things to do and is aimed at human-scale responsiveness. The simple limitation is your operating system. But if the audio sampling itself has dedicated hardware then perhaps by carefully tracking the time when samples were taken and keeping this information with the sample, when your code detects a peak this can be related to when the samples were taken to calculate an “actual” time for the event.

Comment: @barny So switching to C++ and giving process high priority would probably not help either? I'm not sure how the sampling is done, you mean if I use external soundcard instead of integrated one it might have an impact on timing? Main reason I used PC instead of a microcontroller is because I was planning on using an algorithm for peak detection that can be a bit challenging for MCU to complete in desired time interval.

Comment: Unlikely high priority will make much difference, all user-space apps will be interrupted by everything going on with interrupt-driven I/O to disks, USB, etc. I don’t know how soundcards do sampling but yes I’d have thought it should be possible for them to relate the detection time to the sample. Did you try calculating the timing based on the samples rather than when your code detects the peak?

Comment: @barny Yes, thank you, I now based timing on samples rather than time library and results are already much more accurate, down to a millisecond

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're not getting the right timing for the beats is that you're missing chunks of the audio data.  That is, **the chunks are being read by the soundcard, but you're not collecting the data before it's overwritten with the next chunk**.

First, though, for this problem you need to distinguish between the ideas of **timing accuracy** and **real-time response**.

The timing accuracy of a sound card should be very good, much better than a ms, and you should be able to capture all of this accuracy in the data you read from the soundcard.  The real-time responsiveness of your computer's OS should be very bad, much worse than a ms.  **That is, you should easily be able to identify audio events (such as beats) to within a ms, but not identify them at the time they happen (instead, 30-200ms later depending on your system).**  This arrangement usually works for computers because general human perception of the timing of events is much greater than a ms (except for rare specialized percepetual systems, like comparing auditory events between the two ears, etc).

The specific problem with your code is that `CHUNKS` is much too small for the OS to query the sound card at each sample.  You have it at 32, so at 44100Hz, the OS needs to get to the sound card every 0.7ms, which is too short of a time for a computer that's tasked with doing many other things.  If you OS doesn't get the chunk before the next one comes in, the original chunk is overwritten and lost.

To get this working so it's consistent with the constraints above, make `CHUNKS` much larger than `32`, and more like `1024` (as in the PyAudio examples).  Depending on your computer and what it's doing, even that my not be long enough.

If this type of approach won't work for you, you will probably need a dedicated real-time system like an Arduino.  (Generally, though, this isn't necessary, so think twice before you decide that you need to use the Arduino.  Usually, when I've seen people need true real-time it's when trying to do something very quantitave interactive with the human, like flash a light, have the person tap a button, flash another light, have the person tap another button, etc, to measure response times.)

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth explanation. I have changed the algorithm accordingly and am now using sound card's timing and larger chunks. I will post results in after original question to be able to explain what I did with code sample and add results

Comment: My intention was to present user with real-time data, but not every millisecond, but just so often that it looks real-time to a human eye. It was my mistake to confuse accuracy and real-time responsiveness, thank you for clearing that up

Comment: @Terraviper-5: Great to hear it all worked, and thanks for posting the fix and resulting data. As you may know, and if needed, your analysis will run much faster using numpy (but that would be a separate question, of course).